# QGIS 3 export PostGIS layers to DWG

Tags: qgis-3, cad, dwg

I'm having three PostGIS layers (points, lines, polygons) that I'd like to export to a single DWG file.
So far, I could export the layers as an AutoCAD DXF file with a right-click on the layer and choosing Export--> Save Selected Features As ... .
I could read about the export to dwg with a special gdal compilation, but can't use this as we only use a QGIS3 LTR version under windows10.

Does somebody have a workaround for creating the DWG file?

Comment: where did you see that it is not possible to do this in QGIS? what have you tried so far? what other formats can your CAD read in?

Comment: I saw that with a special gdal driver it is possible to write dwg. I have no possibility to compile QGIS with the support of dwg export.

Comment: You can export layers and projects to DXF from QGIS.

Comment: Our CAD can read dxf

Comment: When exporting the PostGIS point layer to dxf i get the following error message: Feature creation error (OGR error: No known way to write feature with geometry 'Multi Point'.) These are the settings i used: Encoding: UTF-8; Symbology export: Symbol layer symbology; Scale: 1:0000; Geometry type:Point